# How to modify game files in Games Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, gaming

I'm using windows 7 and most of the games I'm downloading are in the Windows Games folder. But I can't find a way to modify the file' remove or to do any action, 
Can I remove game so it won't be in the Games folder? Or if there's a way to modify the files?

Comment: Remove files or remove applications?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I have understood your question properly. Nevertheless...

The games that come pre-installed with Windows 7 are considered "features" and the way you show or hide them is this:-

1. Open Control Panel and click **Uninstall a Program** under the Programs
   heading.
2. In the **Programs and Features** dialog box, click **Turn Windows features on or off** in the 
   left-hand panel.
3. Wait for the list to be populated.
4. Expand the **Games** heading and uncheck the games you want to hide.